# More Elegant Loading #container (like google chrome)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, code-snippets

I have a piece of code to display a **simple loading** by clicking for example **on an action** (ajax facet search in my case)

so far it does the job.

/!\
Please don't be confused, read and look at the illustration carefully, there is no code or php file or html modified. we only inject a [snippet](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) and just specifying an empty #div in the page /!\

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
    
    <style>
    #loading-container {
    display:relative;
    }
    .custom-loader {
    z-index:999;
    display:flex;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    align-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;    
    color: white;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none; 
    }
    .custom-loader i{
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    }
    </style>
    
    <script>
    (function($) {
    $(document).on('facetwp-refresh', function() {
    if (FWP.loaded) {$('#loading-container').prepend('<div class="custom-loader facetwp-loading"><i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin"></i><a>Loading...</a></div>');}
            
            });
        
            $(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {
                $('.custom-loader').remove();
            });
        })(jQuery);  
        </script>
        
    <?php } );
```

[image]

**I noticed on very rare occasions** because of the network? or anything else unexplained, the loading **freeze** and we are left to watch [fa-sync](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/animating-icons) **spinning forever**...ouch!very bad for user experience ...

**my question:** how to make it more customizable? to show a message **after x milliseconds** for example.
imagine that the loading time will not exceed 4-5 seconds max otherwise there is a real problem...

([like google chrome no network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC0W4.jpg))

display an error message with a link or button to reset the page.

(in my case it will be reset button onclick = "FWP.reset" )

**so the user knows that something wrong has happened to the current request.**

[image]

I would also like to be able to modify it a little with **personalized messages** for each task for example :

**action when Page Refresh** = Loading...

**action when clic Facet / search-btn** = One moment...

**action reset button** = Page Reset...

so the dear user knows what exactly is going on.

for the moment this is how I make it work

Elementor Editor
[image]

you can see our **hidden div section** this is our **#loading-container**
I redo it in any page or section with facets, I feel that it is not practical..

I must think of a **more elegant way** than that maybe, can be added conditions like
**if facets** in the page then **apply loadings.**

thank you if you understand what I'm talking about and you have a more elegant solution to offer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the FacetWP plugin (please make sure that you mention the plugin name exactly so that we would be able to understand).

I did a quick look at [their documentation](https://facetwp.com/documentation/developers/javascript/) and couldn't find any events/hooks that you can use for your requirements. But you can listen to the `click` events of the search button or the reset button to trigger the display of loading screen. Here's the link to the documentation of the jQuery's `on()` method which you can use to handle the `click` event: https://api.jquery.com/on/

If you are having doubt regarding how to pass the selector to this `on()`, just right click on the button and choose Inspect Element option in your browser(assuming you are using Chrome/Firefox or something). This will give you some idea on how to choose the selector.

Based on [this example](https://facetwp.com/demo/), the click event handler for the button would look something like this:

```
jQuery('.facetwp-icon').on('click', function(){
  alert('button clicked');
});
```

[image]

Also, I would suggest prepending your loading screen only once. Then use the `show()` or `hide()` function of jQuery to display or hide the screen when needed, rather than removing and prepending again!

If you need custom events (rather listening to the click events like I said above), since this is a paid plugin, try pinging the developers. And they probably would help you with the additional code.

Hope I've given you some pointers to start. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed on very rare occasions ... the loading freeze ...

I've recently made a vanilla `.js` loader. I ran into that exact problem and managed to fix it by generating an `<svg>` spinner via javascript and animating it after.

The script create a container prepended to the `<body>` tag, and prepend the `css` to the closing `<head>` tag.

It's probably lighter than any plugins you're using and has no dependencies.

```js
var t="#2774ab",u=document.querySelector("*"),s=document.createElement("style"),a=document.createElement("aside"),m="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",g=document.createElementNS(m,"svg"),c=document.createElementNS(m,"circle");document.head.appendChild(s),(s.innerHTML="#sailor {background:"+t+";color:"+t+";display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;position:fixed;top:0;height:100vh;width:100vw;z-index:2147483647}@keyframes swell{to{transform:rotate(360deg)}}#sailor svg{animation:.3s swell infinite linear}"),a.setAttribute("id","sailor"),document.body.prepend(a),g.setAttribute("height","50"),g.setAttribute("filter","brightness(175%)"),g.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 100 100"),a.prepend(g),c.setAttribute("cx","50"),c.setAttribute("cy","50"),c.setAttribute("r","35"),c.setAttribute("fill","none"),c.setAttribute("stroke","currentColor"),c.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray","165 57"),c.setAttribute("stroke-width","10"),g.prepend(c),(u.style.pointerEvents="none"),(u.style.userSelect="none"),(u.style.cursor="wait"),window.addEventListener("load",function(){setTimeout(function(){(u.style.pointerEvents=""),(u.style.userSelect=""),(u.style.cursor="");a.remove()},100)})
```

**Beside including the script, you have nothing to do. You can have a look the Github and documentation here @ https://github.com/amarinediary/Sailor** there is also a visual demo.

Google's best practice is to have a page speed index under `3` seconds. In `3` seconds you shouldn't be able to read anything. Instead of placeholders saying "wait", you should focus on optimizing your page loading times.

Regarding the "No Network" Google's warning, you can make a similar screen by switching your whole website to a webapp and setup an offline page. It's an easy switch, there is a tones of tutorial out-there.

Answer (score 0):

Create your loading screen with SVG and some custom text underneath it. Wrap it inside a DIV.

Using CSS or `<Style>` set the display equal to block and give it a high Z-index so that it appears above all other HTML elements on the page. This will ensure that the loading screen is displayed when the webpage is first opened.

Use vanilla Javascript to hide the loading screen DIV when the page loads.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //this code will run after the page is fully loaded 
    // just use some javascript to set the loading screen DIV to display none.
  
 document.getElementById("ENTER_DIV_ID_HERE").style.display = "none";

});
```

If you want to call the loading screen again for some other activity such as clicking a button just create a function with vanilla javascript that will toggle the display on and off this can be done with a timer or some other event that you want to use to hide the loading screen again, below example where will will pass the number of mili-seconds that we want the loading screen to display for.

```
    function showLoadingScreenTemporally(numberofMiliSeconds){
    
    //when this function is called we will show the loading screen first
    
    document.getElementById("ENTER_DIV_ID_HERE").style.display = "block";
    
    //then we will hide the loading screen after the specified numberofMiliSeconds has elapsed

setTimeout(function(){

    document.getElementById("ENTER_DIV_ID_HERE").style.display = "none";

}, numberofMiliSeconds);
    
    
}

//then we just need to call this function and pass it the number of mili-seconds that we want to display the loading screen for

showLoadingScreenTemporally(4000);
```

//note I wrote all this just free hand, I have not ran the code coz I am too tired to do so, but thats the general gist of it. Note this is never the way I would implement a loading screen I would always try to tie it to a physical event such as a file upload being completed, etc, rather than just specifying a number of mili-seconds, reason being not all computers are equal some process more quickly than others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your UI to remain responsive even when network connections are lost then the timeouts you have suggested can help, but to consistently handle this you need a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers).

Service workers are how you would implement a custom "You are offline!" message.

Basically, a service worker is a javascript proxy to all your network requests - it runs when someone visits your site, and can respond to requests from your site *even when there is no network connection* either by serving a cached copy, or by serving specific offline messages that your UI JS can handle this for users.

They can also retry poor connections, allowing the occasional drops to just be a slightly slower load by users (rather than asking them to reset/retry manually).

Service workers are a huge topic, but you there are plenty of simple off the shelf implementation (like [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox)) that you can plug in with minimal effort.

Wordpress has an [official plug in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pwa/), and they have examples how to implement [offline](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwa-wp/wiki/Service-Worker#offline--500-error-handling) and [retry](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwa-wp/wiki/Service-Worker#api) support.